# Vtiger update field value from related module

Tags: php, vtiger

I have a code on Save.php of Module Invoice:

```
    public function saveRecord($request) {
        ...
        $received = $request->get('received');
        $balance = $request->get('balance');

        $relProject = $request->get('relProject');
        $project = Project_Record_Model::getInstanceById($relProject);

            $fields = $project->getField('cf_938');
            $fieldInstance = Vtiger_Field::getInstance($fields->id);


            if ($fieldInstance) {
                $fieldInstance->value = $received;
                $fieldInstance->save();
            }
   }
```

Why `save()` is not work? When I save Invoice my field is not update on project.. I need fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Record Model object to edit the record, not the Field Model. Try something like this:

```
public function saveRecord($request) {
        ...
        $received = $request->get('received');
        $balance = $request->get('balance');

        $relProject = $request->get('relProject');
        $project = Project_Record_Model::getInstanceById($relProject);

        $project->set('mode', 'edit');
        $project->set('cf_938', $received);
        $project->save();
   }
```